# Saving an array inside a column of a matrix in numpy shape error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I do some calculation and I get a matrix of size 3 by 3 each time in a loop. Assume that each time, I want to save such matrix in a column of a bigger matrix, whose number of rows is equal to 9 (total number of elements in the smaller matrix). first I reshape the smaller matrix and then try to save it into one column of the big matrix. A simple code for only one column looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
Big = np.zeros((9,3))
Small = np.random.rand(3,3)
Big[:,0]= np.reshape(Small,(9,1))
print Big
```

But python throws me the following error:

Big[:,0]= np.reshape(Small,(9,1))
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (9,1) into shape (9)

I also tried to use flatten, but that didn't work either. Is there any way to create a shape(9) array from the small matrix or any other way to handle this error?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can just do `Big[:,0]= np.reshape(Small,(9))`

Comment: `Big[:,0]` does [`slicing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) and therefore expects a `1D` array, whereas `np.reshape(Small,(9,1))` is a `2D`. So, that's why as suggested by @C_Z_ you could reshape to `1D` array like that or flatten to `1D` with `.ravel()`. So, in summary, you could do : `Big[:,0]= Small.ravel()`.

Comment: Thank you so much C_Z_ and Divakar. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
import numpy as np
Big = np.zeros((9,3))
Small = np.random.rand(3,3)
Big[:,0]= np.reshape(Small,(9,))
print Big
```

or:

```
import numpy as np
Big = np.zeros((9,3))
Small = np.random.rand(3,3)
Big[:,0]= Small.reshape((9,1))
print Big
```

or:

```
import numpy as np
Big = np.zeros((9,3))
Small = np.random.rand(3,3)
Big[:,[0]]= np.reshape(Small,(9,1))
print Big
```

Either case gets me:

```
[[ 0.81527817  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.4018887   0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.55423212  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.18543227  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.3069444   0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.72315677  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.81592963  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.63026719  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.22529578  0.          0.        ]]
```

#### Explanation

the shape of `Big` you are trying to assign to is `(9, )` one-dimensional.  The shape you are trying to assign with is `(9, 1)` two-dimensional.  You need to reconcile this by making the two-dim a one-dim `np.reshape(Small, (9,1))` into `np.reshape(Small, (9,))`.  Or, make the one-dim into a two-dim `Big[:, 0]` into `Big[:, [0]]`.  The exception is when I assigned 'Big[:, 0] = Small.reshape((9,1))`.  In this case, numpy must be checking.

Comment: Thank you piRSquared! Now I know several ways for such implementation!